# Making cairo work on Jupyter notebook with Pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, cairo, oserror

I'm trying to work with a notebook that requires cairo but I get the following error:

```
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
```

I am opening the notebook through Pycharm and work with Windows 10.
I have tried everything I have found on StackOverflow, including [installing GKT+ or UniConverter2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174030/python-cffi-module-fails-when-loading-dll-oserror-0x7e), adding the respective directory to my path to the Project interpreter in the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947494/add-directory-to-python-path-in-pycharm) and restarting Pycharm. Nothing seems to work though.

Any ideas on what might be missing? I'm happy to provide further details that may help answer the question! As you can probably tell, I'm quite a newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: First, you need `cairo`! `OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found` i/e, `cairo` is not installed in this environment... then, maybe, we can help you to "make it work".

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I have cairocffi installed already. Does that help?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I also tried installing python-igraph as suggested [here](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/problem-installing-cairo-library/156) but that didn't seem to work either

Comment: I followed the instructions [here](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows) and it worked! I see where the problem was now. Thanks @ReblochonMasque

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that you've installed a 32bit version of the cairo dll. Installing a 64bit version solved this problem for me: https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases